# Geocoder not finding location during emulator test

Tags: android, database, performance, geocoding, geocode

I am creating an application where you can make several types of accounts, data is stored in an SQLite database, and an address input is verified using Geocoder. However the geocoder only seems to work after I cold boot my emulator or clear the app's storage. I think this is because geocoder is taking too long to get a location and therefore it just throws the exception. However I don't know what would be causing this lag as I have done many things to try and optimize runtime, ie. increase emulator's storage & use Async Tasks. The error message I'm getting is **grpc failed**. Some of the logcat messages are:

```
I/le.walkinclini: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 68211(2747KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 49% free, 3487KB/6974KB, paused 661us total 105.541ms

I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 1600 bytes, containing 1 windows, 7 views

I/Choreographer: Skipped 300 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Answer (score 0):

I caught **grpc failed** even in real devices

I notice when the app is opening, the phone is connecting to wifi then suddenly change to use mobile data, the Geocoder throws this error all the time and cannot reconnect again. Still cannot find any solution to fix this

My solution is when The Geocoder instance throws an error, I use a backup API request that calls to google geocode API. It can be longer but ensure that it success